# The given key was not found error on ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

Suddenly, I've started to get error in my ServiceStack MVC service application as below :

```
{"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}    
System.Exception {System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException}
```

and StackTrace:

```
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Utils.FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(Type requestDtoType) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\Utils\FilterAttributeCache.cs:line 44
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHost.ApplyRequestFilters(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object requestDto) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\EndpointHost.cs:line 201
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\RestHandler.cs:line 79
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack\WebHost.Endpoints\Support\EndpointHandlerBase.cs:line 150
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I've no idea about the error or what wrong is. My app was working and now not working.

Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT 1: When I navigate the service url in my webbrowser,the debugger never reaches to my service classes and `Run` methods.

Comment: Nothing happens suddenly in the programming world. What have you changed in your source code/webhosting?

Comment: Seriously, I've changed nothing in DTOs Models or App_Start\AppHost.cs or else.If you want to know,I can say I've changed a method in the other application in the same solution.But nothing else.I use SVN to track changes and versions.

Comment: Has your web.config or web server changed?

Comment: No,nothing changed and the error comes from ServiceStack codes.

Comment: No one has a chance to work out what's wrong unless you provide the offending source code. The error is being thrown from this line: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Utils/FilterAttributeCache.cs#L44 suggesting there is no service for the requestType the attribute is on. We'd need a stand-alone failing test in order to repro + resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, quite strange! 
Here are the actions I took and did not work.

- Restart IIS and VS 2010.
- Compile the code and debug on VS 2010.
- Compile the code and replace with the content on IIS and restart IIS again.

Here are the action I took and the project started to work again.

- Create a new MVC project.
- Install ServiceStack MVC via NuGet.
- Copy existing codes to new project.
- Rename the namespace in existing code on the new project.
- **Debug on VS2010 and project started to work like a charm.**

When I published the project to the the existing WebSite on IIS , I got the error below :

```
AppHost instance has been already set
```

However, to pass the error, I've deleted the existing website and created a new one.
Than, I've copied the new project output in the new website.

All started work like a charm again.

But I still don't know why I got the errors.

I hope this will help who may have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error from using the wrong model in the routes.

So:

```
Routes.Add<ModelA>("/path/to/service");
```

Should be

```
Routes.Add<ModelB>("/path/to/service");
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but even Hello service example was not working after removing other models and routes.

Comment: I got the exception detailed in the question because I had the wrong model defined against the route